# Segregate data into 4 equal percentage chunks

Tags: r, python-3.x, data.table

I need to segregate the data into 4 equal chunks based on percentage in descending order based on `Qty_ordered` . I tried using `'bins.quantiles'`function (from the binr package) in R but not working. Any other methods which can be used?

```
     Input

     SL.No  Item Qty_Ordered
        1   VT25    2
        2   VT58    4
        3   VT40    10
        4   VT58    2
        5   VT 69   12
        6   VT 67   6
        7   VT45    21
        8   VT 25   16
        9   VT 40   24
        10  VT98    10
        11  VT78    18
        12  VT40    6
        13  VT 25   26
        14  VT85    6
        15  VT78    10
        16  VT25    4
        17  VT40    15
        18  VT69    24

            Output
  SL.No Item Qty Ordered    Class
    1   VT25    2         1
   4    VT58    2         1
   2    VT58    4         1
  16    VT25    4         1
   6    VT 67   6         2
  12    VT40    6         2
  14    VT85    6         2
   3    VT40    10        2
  10    VT98    10        2
  15    VT78    10        3
   5    VT 69   12        3
  17    VT40    15        3
   8    VT 25   16        3
  11    VT78    18        3
   7    VT45    21        4
   9    VT 40   24        4
  18    VT69    24        4
  13    VT 25   26        4
```

Comment: Use `cut` or `findInterval` to create the groups

Comment: How are the chunks equal if there are 5 in Class 1, but only 3 in Class 4? How do you want to make the chunks equal if there are 18 entries?

Comment: @guscht ,The first 25% in descending order of order quantity goes to class 1, next 25% in class 2, so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using the tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "SL.No  Item Qty_Ordered
1   VT25    2
2   VT58    4
3   VT40    10
4   VT58    2
5   VT69   12
6   VT67   6
7   VT45    21
8   VT25   16
9   VT40   24
10  VT98    10
11  VT78    18
12  VT40    6
13  VT25   26
14  VT85    6
15  VT78    10
16  VT25    4
17  VT40    15
18  VT69    24",header = T)

df %>% 
  mutate(Class = findInterval(x = Qty_Ordered, vec = quantile(Qty_Ordered),rightmost.closed = T)) %>%
  arrange(Class)
```

Comment: can we use  smbinning.factor package also for the same

Comment: @pankaj the smbinning package requires you to have a binary (0,1) variable that is associated with the variable you want to bin. The dataset you posted doesn't have a binary (0,1) variable

Comment: ,how to apply  smbinning.factor on this dataset :https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0tjzik0sbdkqpi/Test.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
library(data.table)
test <- fread(input = "SL.No  Item Qty_Ordered
1   VT25     2
2   VT58     4
3   VT40    10
4   VT58     2
5   VT69    12
6   VT67     6
7   VT45    21
8   VT25    16
9   VT40    24
10  VT98    10
11  VT78    18
12  VT40     6
13  VT25    26
14  VT85     6
15  VT78    10
16  VT25     4
17  VT40    15
18  VT69    24", header = T)
setorder(test, Qty_Ordered)
test[, Class := .I %/% ((.N+1)/4) + 1]
test
#     SL.No Item Qty_Ordered Class
#  1:     1 VT25           2     1
#  2:     4 VT58           2     1
#  3:     2 VT58           4     1
#  4:    16 VT25           4     1
#  5:     6 VT67           6     2
#  6:    12 VT40           6     2
#  7:    14 VT85           6     2
#  8:     3 VT40          10     2
#  9:    10 VT98          10     2
# 10:    15 VT78          10     3
# 11:     5 VT69          12     3
# 12:    17 VT40          15     3
# 13:     8 VT25          16     3
# 14:    11 VT78          18     3
# 15:     7 VT45          21     4
# 16:     9 VT40          24     4
# 17:    18 VT69          24     4
# 18:    13 VT25          26     4
```

Comment: You might want to see `?setorder`, `?fread`, `?.N` and `?.I` for some alternatives.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the suggestions. I adjusted the answer. If you have further suggestions, please do not hesitate. :)

Comment: @guscht, can we use smbinning.factor for the same

Comment: @pankaj, I am not aware of that function and `??smbinning` doesnt return any results. Which package is it from? I always try to use as few packages as possible...I think in this case, I would just stick to data.table and not introduce additional packages.

Comment: @guscht, it from library(smbinning). https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smbinning/smbinning.pdf

Comment: @guscht, How will I bin the continuous data like weight  and qty in  below dataset https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0tjzik0sbdkqpi/Test.csv?dl=0  .My target variable is buy_flag